# How to make a synchronous module in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, encryption, module

I already asked the question but I fele like I didn't asked it properly.
I'm trying to make a little encryption module in NodeJS but I have a very hard time with the asynchronous nature of it.

First of, the *result* variable in my main file is *undefined* a milisecond after the script is called, I was expecting that.

Also, the file is processed while the encryption occur, not before.

Note that I do not wish to encrypt the file itself.

The big question:
How can I make everything run smoothly and in order? :D

**www.js**

```
var mod = require('./mymodule.js')
var result = mod.doencrypt();
```

**mymodule.js**

```
module.exports.doencrypt = function() {
    var content = processFile(); //Open a file, increment counter
    var key = generateKey();
    var iv = generateIV();
    var encrypt = doEncryption(content);
    return encrypt;
}

//File manipulation
async function openFile() {
  return new Buffer(await readFile('monolitic.txt', "binary"));
}
async function saveFile(bin) {
  await fs.writeFile("monolitic.txt", bin, "binary", function(err) {
      if(err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          console.log("The monolitic file was saved!");
          return bin;
      }
  });
}
function processFile() {
  console.log("Reading buffer")
   openFile().then(function (bin) {
     monoCounter = bin;
      //Increment
      inc(monoCounter);
      console.log(monoCounter);
      monoCounter = saveMonoCounter(monoCounter);
      return monoCounter;
  }).catch((err) => {
    monoCounter = Buffer.alloc(128);
    saveMonoCounter(Buffer.alloc(128));
  });

}
```

Comment: You need to understand how async and promises actually work.  You can't use `await` with callbacks, and you need to actually return (or `await`) promises.

Comment: Could you provide a slight example with a function from the code above to give me a little example? So if I use callbacks I cannot use awaits? You are talking about the processFile function?